# TextBox validating doesn't work

Tags: c#, validation

I have two textboxes.  I need to validate them before taking any other action.

```
private ErrorProvider _errorProviderEmail = new ErrorProvider();
private ErrorProvider _errorProviderPass = new ErrorProvider();
public FormLogin()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  textBoxEmail.Validating += TextBoxEmailValidating;
  textBoxPass.Validating += TextBoxPassValidating;

  textBoxEmail.Validated += TextBoxEmailValidated;
  textBoxPass.Validated += TextBoxPassValidated;

  textBoxEmail.Text = "";
  textBoxPass.Text = "";
}

void TextBoxPassValidated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _errorProviderPass.SetError(textBoxPass, "");
}

void TextBoxEmailValidated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _errorProviderEmail.SetError(textBoxEmail, "");
}

void TextBoxPassValidating(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxPass.Text)) return;
  e.Cancel = true;
  _errorProviderPass.SetError(textBoxPass,"Password is required!");
}

void TextBoxEmailValidating(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxEmail.Text)) return;
  e.Cancel = true;
  _errorProviderEmail.SetError(textBoxEmail, "Email address is required!");
}
```

The problem is that only validating event for `textBoxEmail` is triggered, what could be wrong here, and why the validating event for `textBoxPass` never fires?

Comment: You need to fill up this question.. The way you presented it there is no way anyone can help you. why are you adding your events dinamic and not static?

Comment: @gbianchi now is more clear for you what's going on there ?

Comment: Does the second event not fire under specific conditions?  If the first one fails validation, does the second one fire?  If the first one _passes_ validation, does the second one fire?

Comment: yes, when i press the button only first one is validated, the second one dont do nothing, and i tried to use textBoxPass.CausesValidation = true; and again nothing happened, any idea ?

Comment: Remove the e.Cancel from both your validating events for now. It may prevent the Validate event from bubbling up to the next event handler. It usually works this way so that it picks up the first error, allowing for the user to correct that error before validating the next one and so on - so if the first validator isn't valid, then the second one never fires - I believe this is the point David was making.

Comment: @dash When the first one is valid the second one does not fire, i will try to check it without e.Cancel. Thanks for hint.

Comment: In addition, the MSDN example only handles the Validated event - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx - it does the check there, not in Validating.

Comment: @dash thanks, i will do the validation in Validated, and you were right, the problem was in e.Cancel, but the example with e.Cancel and errorProvider i took it from msdn too :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The individual TextBox controls only validate when they lose their focus.

Try calling the form's `ValidateChildren()` function to force each control to call their validation handlers:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (this.ValidateChildren()) {
    this.Close();
  }
}
```

Also, you only need one `ErrrorProvider` component.

Answer (score 0):

The `Validating` event is raised only when the control that receives the focus has the `CausesValidation` property set to true.

For example, if you have written code in `TextBox1`'s `Validating` event, and you click the OK button (`CausesValidation = true`) then the Validating event is raised, but if you click the Cancel button (`CausesValidation = false`) then the `Validating` event is not raised.

Source on [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Answers/232913/Validation-is-not-firing#answer1)